# Given $A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & I\\ -I & 0 \end{pmatrix} \\$ Evaluate (in terms of theta): $e^{I\theta A}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am having trouble figuring out how to interpret and approach this particular matrix exponential.

> Given $$A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & I\\ -I & 0 \end{pmatrix} \\$$
> Evaluate (in terms of theta): $e^{I\theta A}$

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is the exponent matrix $I$ (in which case omit it) or is it meant to be $i$?

Comment: The I is meant to denote the identity matrix in this case.

Comment: Why write it there if it's the identity matrix? After all, $IB=B$ (when this makes sense).

Comment: The question is part of a set of review questions for linear algebra that I need to work through as preparation for a course. I can only assume it is there to test if one knows what you just stated. @TedShifrin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint :** notice that $$A^2 = -I$$